# Menu images in jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, menu

How it should work properly?

```
$(".ok").hover(function () {
         $(this).parent().find('.ok').removeClass("ok").addClass("no");
         $(this).removeClass("ok").addClass("no");
     },
     function () {
         $(this).parent().find('.no').removeClass("no").addClass("ok");
         $(this).removeClass("no").addClass("ok");
     }
);
$(".no").hover(function () {
         $(this).parents().children('.no').removeClass("no").addClass("ok");
         $(this).removeClass("no").addClass("ok");
     },
     function () {
         $(this).parents().children('.ok').removeClass("ok").addClass("no");
         $(this).removeClass("ok").addClass("no");
     }
);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/rmtrpkqd/11/**

Now the hovers did not work like it should work.
When I hover "ok" class, the image should change to "no", When I hover "no" class, the image should change to "ok", to all sub menus.
When I hover on Grand Child Sum Menu 2, it change class Menu 1 "ok" to "no" - this is problem

Help me fix it

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code-fixing service... it's not our job to debug your code for you. We can help you to help yourself with your code... but dumping a load of code and saying "what's wrong with it?" just isn't the right way to ask for help. Instead - please be more specific. Tell us: a) what you're trying to do b) what the code is doing instead c) any error messages you got d) any research you have done on the topic before you tried asking us. Then we will be able to help you

Comment: Do you want to change specific menu icon if hover the specific menu? or the menu icon should change for all sub menus?

Comment: This is my code but it is hard to explain. @MohitArora it is not what i want. I want change specific menu icon for all sub menus.

Comment: Explain the desired effect.

Comment: When I hover "ok" class, the image should change to "no", When I hover "no" class, the image should change to "ok", to all sub menus.

Comment: That explanation, provided together with the question, is good enough and descriptive! If you'd provided that from the beginning, people wouldn't (_hopefully_) downvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use on() method of Jquery

```
 $("#yourID").on("mouseover", function () {
           //Your code goes here
        });
```

Comment: I can't use ID. I think so, how you implement it?

Comment: @user2536914 replace "#yourID" with ".ok" and ".no".

Comment: What next? Above is the code that work wrong when I hover on Grand Child Sum Menu 2, it change class Menu 1 "ok" to "no", this is the problem

Comment: your question is not clear, please tell us when you use .ok class and .no class.
When you use .parent() method on .ok class it finds your main div which is <div class="margin-l-300" style="margin-left: 0px;"> and starts finding .ok class and remove .ok class to .no class.

Answer (score 0):

You've described in the comments that you're expecting following behaviour:

o  If `.ok` is hovered, switch that element to `.no`

o  If `.no` is hovered, switch that element and all of its children who are `.no` to `.ok`

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.no', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('no ok');
    $(this).parent('div').find('.no').toggleClass('no ok');
});

$(document).on('mouseover', '.ok', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('no ok');
});
```

With the `$(document).on(EVENT, SELECTOR, FUNCTION())` you are telling the system, to apply your function to the given selector even when you create new elements (or elements get a new class), while in your original form it will only append your function to elements available on pageload.

**Update

Updated according to your comment - this will check every child with `.no` if they have another `.margin-l-300` (which is your indicator in this case, if there are any submenus).

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.no', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('no ok');
    $(this).parent('div').find('.no').each(function(){
        if ($(this).parent().children('.margin-l-300').length != 0)
           $(this).toggleClass('no ok');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it is good but it has one defect, when Grand Child Sum Menu 1 has class "no" and I hover into Menu 1 which has class "no"  -> Grand Child Sum Menu 1 also change class to "ok" , Can Child Sum Menu 1 remember previous state which is class "no" ? It concern with all children Menu 1 in this situation

Comment: I think you've mixed up your namings, as you were talking about "Grand Child Sum Menu 1", and after you're depicting "Child Sub Menu" - but I've updated my code, now it checks if the sub menu has further sub menus: then it applies the change, otherwise it leaves it as is.